# How to sort a group in a way that I get the largest number in the first row and smallest in the second and the second largest in the third and so on

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby, columnsorting

So I have a df like this

```
In [1]:data= {'Group': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
    'Name': [ ' Sheldon Webb',' Traci Dean',' Chad Webster',' Ora Harmon',' Elijah Mendoza',' June Strickland',' Beth Vasquez',' Betty Sutton',' Joel Gill',' Vernon Stone'],
    'Performance':[33,64,142,116,122,68,95,127,132,80]}
In [2]:df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Group', 'Name','Performance'])

Out[1]:
    Group  Name             Performance
0    A     Sheldon Webb       33
1    A     Traci Dean         64
2    A     Chad Webster      142
3    A     Ora Harmon        116
4    A     Elijah Mendoza    122
5    A     June Strickland    68
6    B     Beth Vasquez       95
7    B     Betty Sutton      127
8    B     Joel Gill         132
9    B     Vernon Stone       80
```

I want to sort it in such an alternating way that within a group, say group "A", the first row should have its highest performing person (in this case "Chad Webster") and then in the second row the least performing (which is "Sheldon Webb").

The output I am looking for would look something like this:

```
Out[2]:
    Group   Name             Performance
0    A     Chad Webster      142
1    A     Sheldon Webb       33
2    A     Elijah Mendoza    122
3    A     Traci Dean         64
4    A     Ora Harmon        116
5    A     June Strickland    68
6    B     Joel Gill         132
7    B     Vernon Stone       80
8    B     Betty Sutton      127
9    B     Beth Vasquez       95
```

You can see the sequence is alternating between the highest and lowest within a group.

Comment: I don't know if you can call this as sorting. Pandas sorting accepts a key function that works on a series and returns a series. If you can write a function to do that, you can plug it here. The way that I'd solve this problem is, sort by group, performance and other parameters and then create a new dataframe where we can interleave the highest and lowest performers. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the sorted order and then apply a quadratic function to it where the root is 1/2 the length of the array (plus some small offset). This way the highest rank is given to the extremal values (the sign of the `eps` offset determines whether you want a the highest value ranked above the lowest value). I added a small group at the end to show how it properly handles repeated values or an odd group size.

```
def extremal_rank(s):
    eps = 10**-4
    y = (pd.Series(np.arange(1, len(s)+1), index=s.sort_values().index) 
         - (len(s)+1)/2 + eps)**2
    return y.reindex_like(s)
    
df['rnk'] = df.groupby('Group')['Performance'].apply(extremal_rank)
df = df.sort_values(['Group', 'rnk'], ascending=[True, False])
```

---

```
   Group              Name  Performance     rnk
2      A      Chad Webster          142  6.2505
0      A      Sheldon Webb           33  6.2495
4      A    Elijah Mendoza          122  2.2503
1      A        Traci Dean           64  2.2497
3      A        Ora Harmon          116  0.2501
5      A   June Strickland           68  0.2499
8      B         Joel Gill          132  2.2503
9      B      Vernon Stone           80  2.2497
7      B      Betty Sutton          127  0.2501
6      B      Beth Vasquez           95  0.2499
11     C                 b          110  9.0006
12     C                 c           68  8.9994
10     C                 a          110  4.0004
13     C                 d           68  3.9996
15     C                 f           70  1.0002
16     C                 g           70  0.9998
14     C                 e           70  0.0000
```

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind this

Comment: @Gamerarms I think an example illustrates it best. Regardless of the values, imagine we assign the numbers a rank so they are sorted [1, 2, 3, 4]. We want to now sort this such that we get [4,1,3,2]. There are many ways to do this but one ways is to take the midpoint of that list and subtract then square. So [1,2,3,4] we subtract 2.5 and square. That would become [2.25, 0.25, 0.25, 2.25], so we've succeeded in ranking the outer most values the highest. If we instead subtract off a number slightly smaller than 2.5 (say 2.49) it becomes [2.2201, 0.2401, 0.2601, 2.2801].

Comment: @Gamerarms if it's still unclear, take a look at the graph of `plt.plot(np.arange(-10,11), (np.arange(-10,11)+0.1)**2, marker='o')`. That's offset to the right of 0 slightly, but essentially that's what the `-(len(s)+1)/2 + eps` accomplishes. You can see that for unit steps there is a defined order Y(N) > Y(-N) > Y(N-1) > Y(-N+1), ... > Y(0), essentially accomplishing the interleaving you seek.

Comment: Absolute value will also work instead of squaring the values.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid `groupby` if you use `sort_values` on Performace once ascending once descending, `concat` both sorted dataframes, then use `sort_index` and `drop_duplicates` to get the expected output:

```
df_ = (pd.concat([df.sort_values(['Group', 'Performance'], ascending=[True, False])
                    .reset_index(), #need the original index for later drop_duplicates
                  df.sort_values(['Group', 'Performance'], ascending=[True, True])
                    .reset_index()
                    .set_index(np.arange(len(df))+0.5)], # for later sort_index
                 axis=0)
         .sort_index()
         .drop_duplicates('index', keep='first')
         .reset_index(drop=True)
       [['Group', 'Name', 'Performance']] 
      )
print(df_)
  Group              Name  Performance
0     A      Chad Webster          142
1     A      Sheldon Webb           33
2     A    Elijah Mendoza          122
3     A        Traci Dean           64
4     A        Ora Harmon          116
5     A   June Strickland           68
6     B         Joel Gill          132
7     B      Vernon Stone           80
8     B      Betty Sutton          127
9     B      Beth Vasquez           95
```

Answer (score 3):

Apply the sorted concatenation of `nlargest` and `nsmallest` for each group:

```
>>> (df.groupby('Group')[df.columns[1:]]
      .apply(lambda x:
      pd.concat([x.nlargest(x.shape[0]//2,'Performance').reset_index(),
                 x.nsmallest(x.shape[0]-x.shape[0]//2,'Performance').reset_index()]
            )
            .sort_index()
            .drop('index',1))
      .reset_index().drop('level_1',1))

  Group              Name  Performance
0     A      Chad Webster          142
1     A      Sheldon Webb           33
2     A    Elijah Mendoza          122
3     A        Traci Dean           64
4     A        Ora Harmon          116
5     A   June Strickland           68
6     B         Joel Gill          132
7     B      Vernon Stone           80
8     B      Betty Sutton          127
9     B      Beth Vasquez           95
```

Comment: I am not very proficient with coding,can you please explain this part x.nlargest(x.shape[0]//2,'Performance').reset_index(),
                 x.nsmallest(x.shape[0]-x.shape[0]//2,'Performance').reset_index()

Answer (score 2):

Just another method using custom function with `np.empty`:

```
def mysort(s):
    arr = s.to_numpy()
    c = np.empty(arr.shape, dtype=arr.dtype)
    idx = arr.shape[0]//2 if not arr.shape[0]%2 else arr.shape[0]//2+1
    c[0::2], c[1::2] = arr[:idx], arr[idx:][::-1]
    return pd.DataFrame(c, columns=s.columns)

print (df.sort_values("Performance", ascending=False).groupby("Group").apply(mysort))

        Group              Name Performance
Group                                      
A     0     A      Chad Webster         142
      1     A      Sheldon Webb          33
      2     A    Elijah Mendoza         122
      3     A        Traci Dean          64
      4     A        Ora Harmon         116
      5     A   June Strickland          68
B     0     B         Joel Gill         132
      1     B      Vernon Stone          80
      2     B      Betty Sutton         127
      3     B      Beth Vasquez          95
```

Benchmark:

[image]

Comment: Didn't have time to fix it earlier, but it can be done by simply checking the mid point in advance @Ben.T.

Comment: Quick fix indeed, you just changed the notation from `cur` to `arr`, but nice one :) by curiosity, what is the x-axis in the benchmark?

Comment: Oh it’s just number of tests run. Could do more but too lazy :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try detecting the `min, max` rows with `groupby().transform()`, then sort:

```
groups = df.groupby('Group')['Performance']
mins, maxs = groups.transform('min'), groups.transform('max')

(df.assign(temp=df['Performance'].eq(mins) | df['Performance'].eq(maxs))
   .sort_values(['Group','temp','Performance'],
                ascending=[True, False, False])
   .drop('temp', axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
  Group              Name  Performance
2     A      Chad Webster          142
0     A      Sheldon Webb           33
4     A    Elijah Mendoza          122
3     A        Ora Harmon          116
5     A   June Strickland           68
1     A        Traci Dean           64
8     B         Joel Gill          132
9     B      Vernon Stone           80
7     B      Betty Sutton          127
6     B      Beth Vasquez           95
```

Comment: This does not produce what OP wants though.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind this please.Thank you